# How to change bigint to int in mysql, with table having foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, key, int, bigint

I recently noticed that there are several bigint type fields in one of my databases that could be replaced with type "int". The problem is that the database is already online and in use and also that there are foreign keys in action, so when I try changing the data type in the offline DB, mysql won't let me and produces the error message: "#1025 - Error on rename of (...)".

So how can I change these fields while keeping the foreign keys happy? (and not wiping out the existing DB!)

Comment: Why do you want to change them? Are you encountering performance issues because of them?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm afraid I will eventually. Besides, it's better to do this now than later with a lot more data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't reduce the size of field when it holds data. You can only expand them.
What you can do is export all the data, disable the keys, empty the tables, change the field sizes & import the data again.

Comment: Not true for all cases.. let's say there is no relation on bigint field then it can be changed to int `if there is no value exceeding the limit of int`.. Same you can squeeze varchar length from say 200 to 100 given that no value is bigger than 100 characters

Answer (score 3):

You can alter a column from BIGINT to INT as long as there is not any data in the column that would not fit into the smaller INT datatype.

ALTER TABLE mytable 
  MODIFY COLUMN mycolumn INT(11);

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this question is now more than 3 years old. I don't even remember what database I was talking about. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Add new columns with proper types.
2. Copy values from old columns to new columns.
3. Rename columns.
4. Update constrains (maybe in two steps -- `DROP` and `CREATE`).
5. Drop old columns.